# Performance using D3D10/11 and MDI windows

Tags: winforms, performance, mdi, slimdx, direct2d

I'm working on an MDI app that might hold some a lot (>40) real-time (30 fps) updating graphs; each graph has to potentially render 3D geometry in it. I've tried using Direct2D for each window using SlimDX (on each one) but the performance drops really bad when adding more than 16 windows. Anybody has experience with this whose feedback might be useful?

- I'm currently using the D3D10/11 API which according to the docs has one swap chain per window. On the D3D9 docs, you can switch the window before you present and that's the recommended usage. Should I just try switching to D3D9 instead? Could it be a swap-chain switching issue?
- If it isn't a swap chain issue, would it be perhaps better for me to skip D2D and just manage my own vertex buffers and render using D3D?

Regards!

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. [It's a system to detect spikes on many different modules(timings, heap allocations, etc), so a large number of windows on screen is needed to find out which system misbehaved.]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of performance do you get for one large window/context divided up into >40 cells, with a graph drawn into each (you can use scissor testing to enforce cell boundaries)?

If that is poor, you need to reduce complexity or somehow optimize drawing.

If a single window can render all the content fast enough, consider doing that -- a single window.  Implementing your own maximize / draggable splitter behavior isn't all that hard.

Comment: Yes, that's Plan B. Even before implementing it I think I can safely assume it will not have a performance hit. But with that I lose the built-in niceties of windows, such as resizing individual graphs, built-in context menus, close/minimize window & the most important one I need, a scrollbar for each to see the history. I'd have to rewrite the wheel for each feature...

Comment: @RCaloca: You might try using Windows built-in scrollbar and button controls for at least some of that functionality.  Complex clipping from child controls may or may not cause as much perf hit as so many separate contexts.